# Is it possible to persist VCR cassettes generated from tests run on CircleCI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, circleci-2.0, vcr

We are using [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) to record http requests for our tests in a Rails application. The cassettes are currently committed to source, and every month we rerecord the cassettes manually and commit the new responses to source.

We are using [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/docs/) to run tests automatically. Given that, I want to know is whether it is possible to take advantage of VCR [automatic-recording](https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/3-0-3/docs/cassettes/automatic-re-recording).

I have looked at [artifacts](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/artifacts/) and [caching](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/), but to be honest, I'm not confident I know how those things work well enough to use them in this context, if it is possible.

Any guidance or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: I've never tried automatic-recording specifically but I've been able to integrate VCR with Circle CI in general and a very important component for the integration to work seamlessly for me was this specific setting that goes as part of the VCR config: `config.default_cassette_options = { record: :new_episodes }`

Comment: I'm currently trying to get CircleCI to worker with VCR. CricleCI does not seem to use the cassettes that are saved in the spec folder. Any solution for this ?